# I have a name string, but how do I make it where the person's inputted name is spit back out in a Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#

I have a string `public static string playerName;`and I want to make it where they can input a name for the playerName and then i can put that string in a Console.WriteLine and it says what they put. I am somewhat new to C# and was wondering how I could achieve this.

Comment: Please show us your code.  It is hard to advise you with your code when we can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems so obvious, I am uncertain I understood your problem:

```
using System;
public class C {
    public static string playerName;

    public void M() {
        playerName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(playerName);
    }
}
```

Reading User Input should come shortly after writing Hello World in every toutorial.

Comment: To a beginner it won't be obvious that the last two lines need to be in a method.

Comment: @Amy I asumed he just did not know that `Console.ReadLine()` is a thing, Just that he needed such a thing. But yes, wrong scope would be a possibility.

Comment: @RufusL I put in full code, from SharpLab.

Comment: sorry guys, i come from unity. never used visual studio. my bad, i was simply over thinking it. thank you guys.

Comment: @Volt Understandable mistake. As far s bagage and design patterns go, Console is the least problematic one of the Visual Studio Environments. Indeed it has no inherent design pattern, wich allows you to replicate just about any design pattern. Some people even use the console to debug Windows Services. Only for learning Multitasking and Threading I would absolutely advise against Console. For here my advsie is: BackgroundWoker in Windows Forms. But that should be a while into the future yet.